# ¿Una presentacion como la que esta en la imagen en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

quiero utilizar div para hacer esta misma formacion, saven de algun metodo?
o por si no saben con tablas sera entonces..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El primer método usa los div y col y row, el segundo usa una tabla

```css
.border1,
.border2,
.border3 {
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.border2 {
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.border2,
.border3 {
  border-left: none;
}

.colFix {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> Metodo 1</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="colFix col-xs-6 col-sm-6 border1 ">
        <div class="center-block">
          <h3>TIPO</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="colFix col-xs-6 col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 border2">
            <h3>CAMION</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 border2">
            <h3>MOTOCICLETA</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 border3">
            <h3>BICICLETA</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1> Metodo 2</h1>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" class="border1">Tipo</td>
        <td class="border2">camion</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td  class="border2">Moto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="border3">Bici</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <html> 
 <head>   
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body>   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid #000; height: 20vh; align-items: center;justify-content: center; text-align: center; display: flex;">
                <div style="">
                <h3>TIPO</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid #000; height: 20vh;">
                <div class="row">
                        
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
                        <h3>CAMION</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
                        <h3>MOTOCICLETA</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h3>BICICLETA</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Te recomiendo usar `bootstrap`, copia y pega este código y ejecútalo en pantalla completa, algo así es lo que deseas? si algo comentas...